# Powershell, Server 2012 R2 and determine if cipher suite is active

Tags: powershell, encryption

I have a small project where I have to query about 1800 servers on Server 2012 R2 and want to see if they have TLS 1.2 AND the specific cipher suites that I need enabled on the server AND enabled.

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Using Get-TlsCipherSuite in Server 2016 works as expected, but that is not available in Server 2012 R2.

For Server 2012 R2 I was trying to use this call:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002 -Name Functions
```

But it shows that it is installed, but not it's state. I need to confirm if it is actually enabled and not just installed. The above call doesn't do that, and I can not find where the 'flag' is to show that the item is enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you used `Get-TlsCipherSuite`?

Comment: Get-TlsCipherSuite is not a cmdlet, function, script or operable program for Server 2012 R2. It only works on Server 2016 and higher.

Comment: What does `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` report?

Comment: It returns this.. 5.0.10586.117

Comment: Would the situation change if it were updated to the current Windows PowerShell 5.1 or to add PowerShell Core 7.2?

Answer (score 3):

In my use case I found that the following reliably indicated whether or not the target cipher suites were present and enabled on OS 2012r2

```powershell
$osVer=(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
if (($osVer).GetValue('ProductName') -like "*2012*") {
    Write-Host "detected OS: 2012"
    $2012suites = ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002").Functions).split(",")
"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -in $2012suites) {
        Write-Host "Present: $_" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host "Missing: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the cipher suites aren't (yet) managed by policy. For that, the Local listing is captured with `(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002).functions` . That returns an array, so it doesn't need a `split` for the check for a specific suite to succeed per the rest of the function.